# display open nodes in a GWT Tree

Tags: gwt

I create a GWT Tree, and I would like it to be initially displayed with open nodes. Let's take the standard [Tree example from GWT javadocs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Tree.html):

```
public class TreeExample implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Create a tree with a few items in it.
    TreeItem root = new TreeItem("root");
    root.addItem("item0");
    root.addItem("item1");
    root.addItem("item2");

    // Add a CheckBox to the tree
    TreeItem item = new TreeItem(new CheckBox("item3"));
    root.addItem(item);

    Tree t = new Tree();
    t.addItem(root);

    // Add it to the root panel.
    RootPanel.get().add(t);
  }
}
```

I want it initially displayed as:

```
root
  item0
  item1
  item2
  item3
```

Now, I thought that it was as simple as setting the state of the `TreeItem` that I want to be opened by calling `setState(true)`: [javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TreeItem.html#setState%28boolean%29) for `setState` says "Sets whether this item's children are displayed". However, if I add for example

```
root.setState(true);
```

to the above example, I don't get the expected effect. Apparently nothing changes when I do `root.setState(true);` or `root.setState(false);`: the tree is always displayed with its nodes closed.

How do I get the desired behaviour?

Comment: Just after posting the question I found a way to do almost what I want: I have to call `t.setSelectedItem(item);` to select an item below the root node, and then call `t.ensureSelectedItemVisible();`, which "ensures that the currently-selected item is visible, opening its parents and scrolling the tree as necessary". Is there another way to do it, without explicitly selecting an item?

Comment: `root.setState(true)` works fine for me (GWT 2.0.4 and FF). Can you give us some information about version and browser?

Comment: I'm using GWT 2.0.3 and Firefox 3.6.10. Could it be a bug in GWT 2.0.3?

Comment: Just tested it with 2.0.3 and FF 3.6.10 and it still works. Doesn't seem to be a bug. Did you test the code in a newly created GWT project?

Comment: Yes, I created a new project and tested it in GWT development mode, with GWT Developer Plugin for Firefox, version 1.0.7511. I'm using kubuntu 9.04, with kernel 2.6.28-19.

Comment: Same here except I'm working on mac. It seems that `setState()` has an inconsistent behaviour. Check out http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1187. Did you try to call `setState(true)` just right before adding the `Tree` to the `RootPanel`?

Comment: I got it! The trick is that you must call `root.setState(true)` after having added `root` to the tree, i.e. after having called `t.addItem(root);`. If you do it before, it does not work.

Comment: :) That's what I was thinking. Glad it works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `setState()` depends on the sequence of the method calls to `TreeItem` and `Tree` (as stated [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1187)).

As a rule of thumb call `setState(true)` after adding all the items to the `TreeItem` and after adding the root item to the `Tree`.